# Angular Proxy Partial URL Rewrite Not Occuring as Expected

Tags: angular, proxy

I want to run an Angular 7 app on a dev server and access xml data from a test database (https://demo.aligni.com/api/v2/oid3vLgynoy_Yl1gZkrgkLEq3J/part/000222?find_by=partnumber)

Angular complained righteously about CORS, and SO answers and webpack documentation led me to the same conclusion - create a proxy and rewrite the url to get around my CORS issue.

However, Webpack's pathRewrite is not working as expected to yield the result I want.

I tried setting up the proxy.conf.json file as follows.

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "https://demo.aligni.com/api/v2/",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel":"debug",
        "pathRewrite": {"^api/": ""}
        }
}
```

The Relevant portion from my app.component.ts

```
this.http.get(
    '/api/oid3vLgynoy_Yl1gZkrgkLEq3J/part/728', 
    {
    headers: httpHeaders,
    responseType: 'text'})
    .subscribe((data)=> console.log(data), (err)=>console.log(err));
```

}

My actual results from the proxy.conf.json logging:

```
[HPM] GET /api/oid3vLgynoy_Yl1gZkrgkLEq3J/part/728 -> https://demo.aligni.com/api/v2/
```

Based on the webpack documentation "the configuration below will rewrite the HTTP requests to remove the part /api at the beginning of the URL" [Rewriting URLS of proxy request: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/webpack-dev-server]...
My expected results :

```
GET /api/oid3vLgynoy_Yl1gZkrgkLEq3J/part/728 -> https://demo.aligni.com/api/v2/oid3vLgynoy_Yl1gZkrgkLEq3J/part/728
```

To get the expected results, I would only have to remove the part /api at the beginning of the URL specified in the Angular call (exactly what is stated by the web-pack docs), and add it to my target.

The pathRewrite is removing the entire URL, not just the 'api/' part of it as I would expect.

Of course Angular gives me a 404 as you will get if you visit https://demo.aligni.com/api/v2/

I could not find an example for this use case with pathRewrite, where I actually need part of the URL being sent in.  After a couple hours of searching I've seen some xml path rewrite rules, but I couldn't find a good learning resource. 
 I'd prefer to solve this with pathRewrite if possible. Thanks very much in advance, this is all a bit new to me.

Comment: Not going to work because your domain is not the same, `localhost` != `demo.aligni.com`, beside proxy is only for development time only, you'd run into this later on when moving to production unless they are the same domain.

Comment: In my understanding, the proxy is the ideal way to solve the problem of different domain's.  To me this seems like such a common use case, I'm surprised I couldn't find more on it.  There could also be a proxy in production as well, so my understanding is that this could solve my problem.  I am completely open to other ways of getting this data into Angular, though.  How have you overcome this type of problem?